# How can I import a SHA1 cert into Keystore as PrivateKeyEntry Type instead of trustedCertEntry

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, jks, x509certficiate2

I do have a Jks file (key.jks) in which an existing SHA1 certs(server.cer) with the alias name abc .The certrficate are expired and I have to renew this with the new certs I got . The previous entry was with the entrytype **PrivateKeyEntry** .I have deleted the old entry and I try to import the new certs using the keytool import command it is always adding the entryType as **trustedCertEntry** due to which the handshake is getting failed.The command I am using is below .

keytool -import -keystore key.jks -storepass changeit -alias abc -file server.cer

How can I add this certs as PrivateKeyEntry type . I am using the same alias which was used with the old Certificate .
Any help  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **PrivateKeyEntry** is actually a "Key Pair" with 3 parts. A private key, a public key and a certificate. The certificate may be self-signed or signed by other entity (trusted certificate authority - CA).

A **trustedCertEntry** is only a certificate with the assigned public key (no private key).

When a certificate expires, you can either create a new keypair, a certificate signing request (csr) and when the CA issues a new certificate, you can import the certificate reply.

Sometimes the CA may issue a new certificate for the same public key, so you just need to import the reply.

Importing the certificate (reply) - you actually did well the second part. If you import a certificate and there is already an existing keypair (PrivateKeyEntry), the keytool checks if the certificate matches the public key and then replaces the old certificate with the new one keeping the private key.

The problem is that **you did delete your private key**. I hope you have a backup. If not, I'd suggest to create a new keypair and request a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your response .I do have a the old backup file .Can i try to add new certs without deleting the old Certificate ? Would it replace the existing one with the  new one wiith privateKeyEntry EntryType.

Comment: @liam create a copy of the backup and try out. If the certificate is made for the same kepair, then yes, the certificate will be replaced for the same private key

Comment: So basically it does not work on the top of the existing certs . It gives the error as public keys in reply and keystore does not matches .So the CA has issued new certs . Can you pls provide me some guidance link how should I go ahead in this case . Do i need to share the same public key and certs with the client as well ?  Sorry I am completely new to this process

Comment: @Liam: if the new cert doesn't match the old keyentry, the CA has not just issued a new cert, it has issued a new cert for a NEW KEYPAIR and CSR. If you sent that CSR, you must have generated the new keypair -- use it. If someone else sent the CSR, get the new keypair from them. Also, if the server reply does not already include any needed _chain_ cert(s) after the server cert, either add them to the reply or make sure they are separately in the keystore (as trustedCertEntry's) before you import. (What chain cert(s) are needed depends on the CA which you didn't identify or describe.)